# change radomly background color

Tags: javascript

I have some simple code that randomly changes the background color on the page. Why do I need to use `let letters = "0123456789ABCDEF".split('')` in the code?

```js
function changeColor() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor()
}

function getRandomColor() {
  let color = "#";
  let letters = "0123456789ABCDEF".split('');
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

function test() {
  changeColor();
  setInterval(changeColor, 1000)
}

test();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `"0123456789ABCDEF"` string is effectively a list of all characters available in hexadecimal. The `split()` call turns this in to an array, which is then randomly accessed 6 times to create a random colour in hex.

An alternative one-line method to do this would be to generate a random number between 0 and the upper limit (which for 6 hex characters is 16^6, or specifically 16,777,215) and then turn this in to a hex value using `toString(16)`:

```js
const randomHex = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(16, 6)).toString(16);
console.log(randomHex);
```

Answer (score 0):

A color is hexadecimal string (base 16) made of 6 character (7 include the #).

Answer (score 0):

the function is to getRandomColor, color consists of hexadecimal digits.
"let letters = "0123456789ABCDEF".split('');"
the expression is meant to convert a string "0123456789ABCDEF" to an array ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E']

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The split creates an array of letters so it can be crawled with the for{} loop.

The for loop then creates and concatenes a 6 characters string by taking a random value from the letters table (a random character in the ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"] set).

The Math.floor(Math.random() * 16) code gives you a number between 1 and 16 (one of the random 16 keys in the letters table) because Math.random() outputs for example :

- rand gives you 0.6705686567474212
- rand * 16 : 10.729098507958739
- floored : 10
- letters[10] = 9

So your first loop gives you #9

Loop it 5 more times and you get #9536AF